# extracting node values & attribute values (parent & child nodes) from large nested xml document using php

Tags: php, xml, export-to-csv, xmlreader

I am trying to extract extracting node values & attribute values (parent & child nodes)  from large nested xml document. The output should be in form of a table. With my code I can extract text values named "N2:NameElement N2:ElementType="FullName"" and attribute values named "PartyID" of the parent node (N8:Entity), but not the attribute value named "N5:IndustryCode" of the child node "N5:OrganisationInfo" [see my output table - the column for attribute value of N5:IndustryCode is blank](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsd2YzR09aWlZIejQ/view?usp=sharing). This is my dummy file is: [xml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsODUzbWpQbm5SaWM/view?usp=sharing)

The target child node attribute is named "N5:IndustryCode" under the tag named "N5:OrganisationInfo".

This is my code:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting ( E_ALL );
 ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);

 $reader = new XMLReader();

 $reader->open("xmlfile.xml");
 $fo = fopen("companiesNameNzbnBizClassification_WholeData1.csv", "w" );
 fputs($fo, "name, ID,businessClassification".PHP_EOL);
 while ( $reader->read())    {

if ( $reader->name == 'N8:Entity'  &&
        $reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT &&
        $reader->localName == 'Entity' && $reader->localName == 
 'IndustryCode')    {
            $name = null;
            $businessClassification = null;
            $ID = null;
            $newNode = $reader->expand();

            $nameNode = $newNode->getElementsByTagName('OrganisationName');
            if ( $nameNode->length > 0 ){
                $name = $nameNode[0]->getElementsByTagName('NameElement')-
 >item(0)->nodeValue;
            }

            $ID = (string)$reader->getAttribute('PartyID'); 
            $businessClassification = (string)$reader-
 >getAttribute('IndustryCode');             

            $newName = str_ireplace(","," ",$name);
            fputs($fo,  
  $newName.",".$ID.",".$businessClassification.PHP_EOL);

        }       
 }
 fclose($fo);
```

I will be glad for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong with your sample code: ``$reader->name == 'N8:Entity' && $reader->name == 'N5:OrganisationInfo'`` How can ``$reader->name`` have two different values at the same time?

Comment: Thanks kmoser. I have removed the && $reader->name == 'N5:OrganisationInfo' from the if statement, with the understanding that 'N8:Entity' is the parent node. But still, the column for attribute value of N5:IndustryCode is still blank. 'N5:IndustryCode' is a child node to 'N8:Entity'. With this code, I can extract text values named "N2:NameElement N2:ElementType="FullName"" and attribute values named "PartyID" of the parent node (N8:Entity). I do not have idea where  the problem is.